# How do I change the runlevel?

Tags: init

How can i change the runlevel in ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10
As far as I can recall ubuntu changed the runlevel with something else?

If I want to change the start to terminal only and not X what and r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Ubuntu boot directly to console and not X, you have to do the following:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favorite text editor as root (e.g. `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`)
2. Locate the following line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. Replace `"quiet splash"` with `"text"` (i.e., `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`). If you have a specific runlevel in mind, use that number (for runlevel 3: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="3"`).
4. Save the file
5. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```